# Code has the same variable called and uncalled and there is not an error message available

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

What is wrong with this code? I don't even get an error message

```
def efficient_return(mean_returns, cov_matrix, target):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)
def portfolio_return(weights):
    return portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)[1]
    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: portfolio_return(x) - target},
                   {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bounds = tuple((0,1) for asset in range(num_assets))
    result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result
```

As you can see in the screenshot, `mean_returns` and `cov_matrix` are not called in the fifth line even though they are called in the first line. Also, I am puzzled by the variable `target` as it is not defined anywhere in the code example.

[image]

Here's all the code and libraries

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import scipy.optimize as sco

stocks = ['HSBC','JPM','TSLA','WMT','AMZN','COST']
pf_data = pd.DataFrame()   
for stock in stocks:
    pf_data[stock] = web.DataReader(stock, data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2008-1-1')['Adj Close']
num_stocks = len(stocks)

def portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights ) *252
    std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
    return std, returns
def random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios))
    weights_record = []
    for i in range(num_portfolios):
        weights = np.random.random(len(stocks) )
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        weights_record.append(weights)
        portfolio_std_dev, portfolio_return = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
    return results, weights_record
def neg_sharpe_ratio(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    p_var, p_ret = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    return -(p_ret - risk_free_rate) / p_var
def max_sharpe_ratio(mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bound = (0.0,1.0)
    bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))
    result = sco.minimize(neg_sharpe_ratio, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args,
                        method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result
def portfolio_volatility(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    return portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)[0]
def min_variance(mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bound = (0.0,1.0)
    bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))
    result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args,
                        method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result

def efficient_return(mean_returns, cov_matrix, target):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)
def portfolio_return(weights):
    return portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)[1]
    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: portfolio_return(x) - target},
                   {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bounds = tuple((0,1) for asset in range(num_assets))
    result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result

    
def efficient_frontier(mean_returns, cov_matrix, returns_range):
    efficients = []
    for ret in returns_range:
        efficients.append(efficient_return(mean_returns, cov_matrix, ret))
    return efficients
def display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate):
    results, weights = random_portfolios(num_portfolios,mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
    
    max_sharpe_idx = np.argmax(results[2])
    sdp, rp = results[0,max_sharpe_idx], results[1,max_sharpe_idx]
    max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[max_sharpe_idx],index=pf_data.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
    max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T
    
    min_vol_idx = np.argmin(results[0])
    sdp_min, rp_min = results[0,min_vol_idx], results[1,min_vol_idx]
    min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[min_vol_idx],index=pf_data.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
    min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T
    
    print ("-"*80)
    print ("Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print ("Annualised Return:", round(rp,2))
    print ("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp,2))
    print ("\n")
    print (max_sharpe_allocation)
    print ("-"*80)
    print ("Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print ("Annualised Return:", round(rp_min,2))
    print ("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp_min,2))
    print ("\n")
    print (min_vol_allocation)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    plt.scatter(results[0,:],results[1,:],c=results[2,:],cmap='YlGnBu', marker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.scatter(sdp,rp,marker='*',color='r',s=500, label='Maximum Sharpe ratio')
    plt.scatter(sdp_min,rp_min,marker='*',color='g',s=500, label='Minimum volatility')
    plt.title('Simulated Portfolio Optimization based on Efficient Frontier')
    plt.xlabel('Annualised Volatility')
    plt.ylabel('Annualised Returns')
    plt.legend(labelspacing = 0.8)
def display_calculated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate):
    results, _ = random_portfolios(num_portfolios,mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
    
    max_sharpe = max_sharpe_ratio(mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
    sdp, rp = portfolio_annualised_performance(max_sharpe['x'], mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(max_sharpe.x,index=pf_data.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
    max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T
    
    min_vol = min_variance(mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    sdp_min, rp_min = portfolio_annualised_performance(min_vol['x'], mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(min_vol.x,index=pf_data.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
    min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T
    
    print ("-"*80)
    print ("Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print ("Annualised Return:", round(rp,2))
    print ("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp,2))
    print ("\n")
    print (max_sharpe_allocation)
    print ("-"*80)
    print ("Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print ("Annualised Return:", round(rp_min,2))
    print ("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp_min,2))
    print ("\n")
    print (min_vol_allocation)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    plt.scatter(results[0,:],results[1,:],c=results[2,:],cmap='YlGnBu', marker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.scatter(sdp,rp,marker='*',color='r',s=500, label='Maximum Sharpe ratio')
    plt.scatter(sdp_min,rp_min,marker='*',color='g',s=500, label='Minimum volatility')
    target = np.linspace(rp_min, 0.40, 50)
    efficient_portfolios = efficient_frontier(mean_returns, cov_matrix, target)
    plt.plot([p['fun'] for p in efficient_portfolios], target, linestyle='-.', color='black', label='efficient frontier')
    plt.title('Calculated Portfolio Optimization based on Efficient Frontier')
    plt.xlabel('Annualised Volatility')
    plt.ylabel('Annualised Returns')
    plt.legend(labelspacing = 0.8)
```

The example is found [here](https://amangupta16.medium.com/portfolio-optimization-using-python-part-1-2-9fd80097a606)

Comment: `mean_returns` and `cov_matrix` are local variables in the `efficient_return` function. They're not in scope in the `portfolio_return` function.

Comment: Also with `return` on first line of `portfolio_return` function the rest of the code in the function body will never be executed. Note that it is dimmed in the screenshot.

Comment: This looks like a formatting error in the article. The `portfolio_return` function should be indented one more level (it's a closure in the `efficient_return()` function).

Comment: @yut23 The wrong indentation is also in the screenshot, which is why the IDE has squiggled the variables.

Comment: @Barmar, I think yut23 refers to the article linked at the end of OP question.

Comment: Indeed the issue was with the lacking indention of the ```portfolio_return``` function. Thanks @yut23.

Comment: Note that there are better formulations for the max Sharpe-ratio problem. Consult the relevant literature.